Connect outputs from separate boxes to two different inputs on one box in CODESYS Function Block Diagram
In CODESYS FBD, is it possible to connect outputs from two separate boxes to different inputs on one box, like in the image? If so, how?
The reason I wish to do this is to not repeat the logic that outputs some_output which may depend on many input signals.


And this is why I prefer ST over everything else. I'd assume that you, with your web development background, would be the same? Anyways, in such situations I'd consider creating a function to handle what you are trying to do and just pass the variables as inputs.

I have written hundreds of thousands of lines of ST, and literally zero graphical program elements, so I wish I could provide a technically correct answer but I can't. Graphical programming is less expressive for any given level of verbosity. Due to their training, some people feel diagrams are "simpler" or "more clear", but as soon as you start engineering something meaningful, they get in the way. General software development is done with text-based languages, not diagrams, and it is not because software developers are stupid while the automation world has "seen the light".
